# Must fOAEP padding go hand in hand for encryption and decryption?

Tags: encryption, rsa

Is it possible to Decrypt data using RSACryptoServiceProvider with fOAEP set to true if the data being decrypted does not conform to OAEP padded cipher text? i.e. fOAEP set to false for during data Encryption

```
public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] rgb, bool fOAEP);
```

Are there any Caveats to this scenario? Must fOAEP padding go hand in hand for encryption and decryption?

Comment: No, that won't work thankfully. OAEP de-padding includes a number of checks which are have almost zero probability of succeeding if the OAEP padding was not applied to the original plaintext. See [OAEP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#section-7.1.2)

Comment: Thank you for the response and link to additional information 
With that said, would the contrary also not hold true?
If OAEP padding is applied to the encrypted text, is it possible to decrypt the text without OAEP padding

Comment: No, the OAEP transformation includes a "feistel-like" step that completely obscures the original plaintext. Without reversing those steps the result appears to be a bunch a random bytes.